# Optimizing methods with multiple if checks on getter values

Tags: java, object-oriented, complexity, cyclomatic-complexity

I have a method where I fetch user input, check if certain values exist, and based on that build my own custom input object that I would use to search in a database. The code for the search method is as follows.

```
public SearchDocumentResult searchData(EmployeeInput employeeInput) {
    EmployeeInput getEmployeeInputForSearch = buildApplicationInputForSearch(employeeInput);
    if (employeeInput != null) {
        return super.searchForExactData(getEmployeeInputForSearch);
    } else {
        return super.searchForCloseMatchData(getTestPersonInput);
    }
}
```

The methods with multiple if checks on the input are as follows. Both the below methods and the above method exist in the same class.

```
private Application buildApplicationInputForSearch(Application applicationInput) {
    Application.Builder applicationForSearch = Application.builder();
    String jobIdFromInput = applicationInput.getJobId();
    applicationForSearch.withIsTagged(applicationInput.isTagged());
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(jobIdFromInput)) {
        applicationForSearch.withJobId(jobIdFromInput);
    }
    FormSection formSectionInput = applicationInput.getFormSection();
    if (formSectionInput != null) {
        this.buildFormSectionInputForSearch(formSectionInput);
    }
    return applicationForSearch.build();
}

private FormSection buildFormSectionInputForSearch(FormSection formSectionInput) {
    FormSection.Builder formSectionForSearch = FormSection.builder();
    String formCountry = formSectionInput.getCountry();
    Map<String, String> employeeQuestions = formSectionInput.getEmployeeQuestions();
    Map<String, String> applicationQuestions = formSectionInput.getApplicationQuestions();
    List<String> formNames = formSectionInput.getNames();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(formCountry)) {
        formSectionForSearch.withCountry(formCountry);
    }
    if (formNames.size() > 0) {
        formSectionForSearch.withNames(formNames);
    }
    if (employeeQuestions.size() > 0) {
        formSectionForSearch.withEmployeeQuestions(employeeQuestions);
    }
    if (applicationQuestions.size() > 0) {
        formSectionForSearch.withApplicationQuestions(applicationQuestions);
    }
    return formSectionForSearch.build();
}
```

The `EmployeeInput` is a model class that gets generated through a library and therefore I cannot make that use Java Optional for fields that may or may not exist. Using this `EmployeeInput` object as it is, how can I make this code more readable, with less if conditions? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (formSectionInput != null) {
        this.buildFormSectionInputForSearch(formSectionInput);
    }
```

can be replaced with:

```
Optional.ofNullable(formSectioninput).map(this::buildFormSectionInputForSearch);
```

I dont understand the need of `if` condition in the statements like below:

```
if (formNames.size() > 0) {
        formSectionForSearch.withNames(formNames);
    }
```

If you are expecting that formNames can be null then you should not use `.size()`, it can throw `NullPointer` exception. You should do similar to above example:

```
Optional.ofNullable(formNames).map(formSectionForSearch::withNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the condition - *if it is not contextual* - into the guarded method:

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(formCountry)) {
    formSectionForSearch.withCountry(formCountry);
}
if (formNames.size() > 0) {
    ...
}
```

So:

```
formSectionForSearch.withCountry(formCountry);
formSectionForSearch.withNames(formNames);

void withCountry(String formCountry) {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(formCountry)) {
        ...
    }
}

void withNames(List<String> formNames) {
    if (!formNames.isEmpty()) {
        formSectionForSearch.withNames(formNames);
    }
}
```

On reuse in N call sites (here unlikely) it will even reduce code. And it creates more secure code for calling the method.